# an IF for journals in a bibTex bst style file

Tags: bibtex

Currently, in my `.bst` file using BibTex, if an entry has both a Journal and an arXiv link, both are used in the citation. What I would like to do is use an "if" statement saying that if a Journal is defined, don't print the arXiv reference.

Any ideas?

I've uploaded the style file [here](http://jwsmith.web.cern.ch/jwsmith/PDFs/Style.bst) if that helps.

Comment: You can make it much easier for people to help you if you also show a few example `.bib` entries that we can experiment with as well as the expected output for those entries. I spent quite a bit of time figuring out how your `eprint` setup works in the first place, that time could have been massively reduced had I actually seen a few entries in action. So even for questions like this an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) (in this case) has its uses.

Comment: Aha, sorry about that. I could have definitely added a working example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.bst` replace the function for `article` with

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.collaboration output
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.title "title" output.check
  blank.sep
  crossref missing$
  { journal missing$   
    {}
    { format.journal add.doi "journal" output.check }
    if$
  }
  { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
    format.pages output
  }
  if$
  journal missing$
    { format.eprint output
      format.url output }
    'skip$
  if$
  note output
  new.sentence
  format.SLACcitation output
  fin.entry
}
```

The new bit is

```
  journal missing$
    { format.eprint output
      format.url output }
    'skip$
  if$
```

instead of

```
  format.eprint output
  format.url output
```

That means that now the `eprint` and `url` information is only printed if the `journal` field is absent.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
  journal = {Civil Service Review},
  volume  = {138},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {234-289},
  archive = arXiv,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint  = {1234.5689},
}
@article{elk,
  author  = {Anne Elk},
  title   = {On Brontosauruses},
  year    = {1972},
  archive = arXiv,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  eprint  = {2234.5689},
}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby,elk}
\bibliographystyle{jwsmith}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: 1 E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments, Journal of Computational Chemistry 19 (1998) 377–395.//H. Appleby, On the Importance of the Civil Service, Civil Service Review 138 (1980) 234–289.//A. Elk, On Brontosauruses, arXiv:2234.5689.]